# Stability of optimal transference mappings (Exercise 2.17 in Villani's Topics in Optimal Transportaiton)

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, optimal-transport

I'm really stuck on the first part of this exercise. I've tried to type it up in a fashion that is as self-contained as possible, but some background in optimal transport is likely required to read this.

Let $P_{ac,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the space of absolutely continuous probability measures with finite second moments. Suppose $\sigma \in P_{ac,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is given, as well as a family $\rho_k \in P_{ac,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that weakly converges to some $\rho \in P_{ac,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Let $\nabla \varphi_k$ be the optimal mapping of the Monge problem with quadratic cost between $\sigma$ and $\rho_k$, i.e. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |x-\nabla \varphi_k(x)|^2 d\sigma(x) = \inf_{T \# \sigma = \rho_k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |x - T(x)|^2 d\sigma(x)$$
Here, the infimum is taken over functions $T : x \mapsto T(x)$ satisfying the pushforward constraint. Similarly, we can define $\nabla \varphi$ between $\sigma$ and $\rho$.

Let $d\pi_k(x,y) = d\sigma(x) \delta(y = \nabla \varphi_k(x))$, and similarly define $\pi$ between $\sigma$ and $\rho$.

How can I show that $\pi_k$ weakly converges to $\pi$? (The hint given is to note that the optimal transference plan is unique.)

Comment: I would try the following: by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the sequence $\pi_k$ must have a convergent subsequence in the weak* topology (aka "weak convergence of measures"). Let $\pi^\prime$ denote the limit of this convergent subsequence. Show that $\pi^\prime$ is an optimal transport plan. But by the uniqueness of the optimal transport plan we must have that $\pi^\prime=\pi$, and since $\pi_k$ has only one limit point, it must (again by compactness, thanks to Banach-Alaoglu) converge to $\pi$.

Comment: Brilliant! This makes a ton of sense; thanks.